# Filter foreign key column on choice in flask admin

Tags: python-2.7, sqlalchemy, relation, flask-admin

I am using Flask-admin and SQLAlchemy.
I want to limit the choices of a foreign key based on a choice of the foreign key of the parent table.

```
class City(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'city'
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   name = Column(String, nullable=False)

   def __unicode__(self):
      return self.name

class Street(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'street'
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   name = Column(String, nullable=False)
   city = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(City.id), nullable=False)
   city_ref = relationship(City) 

   def __unicode__(self):
      return self.name

class Adress(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'adress'
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   familiyname = Column(String, nullable=False)
   street = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Street.id), nullable=False)
   street_ref = relationship(Street)
   city_ref = relationship("City", 
              secondary="join(Street,City,Street.city==City.id)",
              primaryjoin="and_(Adress.street==Street.id)",
              secondaryjoin="City.id == Street.city") 

   def __unicode__(self):
      return self.name
```

Now I want to add an adress for a family. But first I want to select the city and based on that choice I want to filter the available streets.
How can this be done?

```
admin.add_view(sqla.ModelView(Adress, db.session))
```

This also shows the city but the street column is not filtered when a city is chosen.